# How to use Content Query by query string parameters

Tags: content-query-web-part, query

I need my Content Query Web Part to show some content which depends on a Value of a property. Now I had no problem doing it "statically", putting in the properties the filter like:

Column is equal to staticvalue

I want my content query to become:

Column is equal to QueryString value

Is there any out of the box way to do this? I must extend the webpart programmatically?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use PageQueryString and/or PageFieldValue in the CQWP.

Here is an [exmaple](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.no/2011/09/cqwp-pagequerystring-and-pagefieldvalue.html)

Comment: Link is now broken - don't use links as the example - summarize their content in case they go away.  What you wanted to say was, if say, "?Category=Finance" was the query string, you filter by indicating you want to filter on the "Category" field on the list, and set it to `equals` the value `[PageQueryString:Category]`, where that value indicates the name `Category` that was supplied in the URL.